# XMPP: Connect to GTalk

Tags: php, xmpp

Am using XMPP trying to connect to Gtalk to send a message from one of my other gtalk accounts to my main account from a PHP page. I get an error that its unable to connect before timeout. Please advise.

Comment: we'll need to see some code and the error output in order to be of any assistance. this sounds like it might be a firewall issue instead of a code issue

Answer (score 1):

XMPP has different feature, authentication methods: Gtalk server requires:

- The service is hosted at talk.google.com on port 5222 (indeed 443 is working as well)
- TLS is required
- The only supported authentication mechanism is SASL PLAIN

Refer to [Google Talk for Developers - Open Communications](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html)